Multiprocessing not working with OpenAI Class instance object
I have a 3 class, the first class common class used to initiate the AzureOpenAI connection with different python module. 2nd class used the first class to embed the word/sentence and 3rd class used to multiprocessing and other preprocessing. But its throwing error TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
class OpenAI:
    def __init__(self, api_key: str, api_base: str, api_version: str, pools_n: int = DEFAULT_POOLS_N):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_base = api_base
        self.api_version = api_version
        
    def define_openai_client(self): #, api_key: str, api_base: str, api_version: str
        try:
            client = AzureOpenAI(api_key=self.api_key,
                                azure_endpoint=self.api_base,
                                api_version=self.api_version)
            return client
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating OpenAI client: {e}")
            return None

class OAIConnection:
    def __init__(self, api_key: str, api_base: str, api_version: str, pools_n: int = DEFAULT_POOLS_N):
        try:
            self.client = OpenAI(api_key, api_base, api_version).define_openai_client()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def embed_sentence(self, sentence: str)
        try:
            response = self.client.embeddings.create(input=sentence,
                                                model=TEXT_EMBEDDING_ADA
                                                )
        except (ValueError, BadRequestError):
            # that's a way of filling missing values by zeros-vector
            return [0] * LENGTH_OF_OPENAI_EMBEDDINGS
        return response.data[0].embedding

class OAIEmbeddings(OAIConnection):
    
    def __init__(
            self, api_key: str, api_base: str, api_version: str, pools_n: int = DEFAULT_POOLS_N
    ):

        super().__init__(api_key, api_base, api_version, pools_n)
        # self.lock_file: Lock = Lock()
        self.embeddings_storage: dict = {}
        self.pools_n = pools_n
        self.logger = logging.Logger(level=os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'), name=self.__class__.__name__)

    def embed_sentences(self, sentences: List[str]) -> dict:

        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.pools_n) as pool:
            results = pool.map(self.embed_sentence, sentences)

        return results

mainly the issue is due to the self.embed_sentence. How can I remodify code to make it working?
Expectation
I need to finally call the class OAIEmbeddings with openai keys to make code working.
Test:
sentence = OAIEmbeddings(openai_key, openai_base, openai_version)
result = sentence.embed_sentences(['Hello'])
result

